# What are the arguments I can use with strings command line tool?

Tags: macos

```
s cat SOMETHING.DAT | strings -n 8
```

I had gotten the right half of the example from Wikipedia; but I wish I had a list of all the arguments that I can pass to the `strings` tool.

I am trying to figure out how to get some useable data from .DAT files that were part of a DOS program written by someone who is no longer alive.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strings 
[-] [-a] [-o] [-t format] [-number] 
[-n number] [[-arch <arch_flag>] ...] [--] [file ...]
```

These seem to be the available arguments, but I cannot find any type of description or help file.

Comment: run the command `man man`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about documentation for a command-line utility's parameters and not programming.. The poster should just read the documentation. At best, this question is more appropriate for [linux.se] or [apple.se] instead.

Comment: Thank you, but it just lists the same things as above with the addition of a generic description of the `strings` tool

Comment: I did not have the documentation until just now, but the documentation does not actually tell you what the arguments mean

Comment: `man strings` on OS X tells me quite a lot about what the arguments mean.

Comment: I see it now thankyou

Comment: If someone puts the 'man strings' solution into an answer, I will mark it as the Accepted Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tools come with a man page, which has a more detailed documentation. You can access it by supplying the tool name as argument. For `strings` that is:

```
man strings
```

The documentation page also contains the hint that the algorithm used by `strings` is quite primitive, so don't raise your hopes too much.

The .DAT extension is used for a lot of things, try loading the file into a hex-viewer and see if that helps (try `man hexdump`).

The only reliable way to understand how the file is structured is to trace the execution of the program that reads/writes it (e.g. by looking at the disassembly).